# Optimum Update frequency for a client server based multiplayer game

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am making a multiplayer game in c++ :

The clients simply take commands from the users, calculate their player's new position and communicate it to the server. The server accepts such position updates from all clients and broadcasts the same about each to every. In such a scenario, what parameters should determine the time gap between consecutive updates ( i dont want too many updates, hence choking the n/w). I was thinking, the max ping among the clients should be one of the contributing parameters.

Secondly, how do i determine this ping/latency of the clients ? Other threads on this forum suggest using "raw sockets" or using the system's ping command and collecting the output from a file .. do they mean using something like `system('ping "client ip add" > file')` or forking and exec'ing a ping command..

Comment: First of all your basic concept is flawed. Send the COMMANDS to the server, NOT the positions. Otherwise you'll end up with more cheaters than you can think of. Secondly, the update rate depends on the type of your game in case of my http://github.com/BonsaiDen/NodeGame-Shooter thing, 50-300ms is enough. The bigger the timespan between your updates the more interpolation you'll have to do.

Comment: Ivo, u r right, there is a lot of scope for cheating clients if i send the positions, but i figured, that since i m using UDP to send these update packets, if "position" updates are lost in transit then the damage to the game wouldn't be as severe as if the 'commans' updates are lost, in which case ill also have to keep synchronizing regularly with each client their correct positions ... Are u also suggesting that the update frequency should not be a function of the network performance (for example if the network is heavily loaded / relatively free) ?

Comment: I you base the frequency on player ping it'd be easy for some one to slow down the whole game just by increasing his ping. Have you done some testing? Is UDP a fundamental requirement? What about non position stuff? Like firing, casting, clicking UI. Do you want to use UDP for that too? You'll end up with a lot of client side logic and tons of crazy server side validation code this way.

Comment: everywhere i read , they tell me i gotta use UDP for sending update packets, as they are gonna be frequent nad real time (a lost packet is better than a delayed packet, right ?). Although u have raised the serious issue about scalability in the type of commands that can be handled by the client .. (the server checks keep getting more complicated). So whats the solution ? sending only the commands from client to server and then also keeping the universe synchronized by sending periodic synchronizing updates ?

Comment: Sending commands is the easiest way to get things right, and getting things right is always better than just getting them to perform well. I don't know the scale of your game, but I would suggest that you go with TCP at first. Since it seems that this is your first multiplayer project, it's far more important that you grasp the concepts you need to keep the world secure and in sync. Games like WoW will do a mix of TCP and UDP, but keep in mind they have 1000 times the experience and 100x the people to program both server side and client side checks(like warden which watch the game process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is going to depend on what kind of a multiplayer game you are talking about. It sounds like you are talking about an mmo-type game.
If this is the case then it will make sense to use an 'ephemeral channel', which basically means the client can generate multiple movement packets per second, but only the most recent movement packets are sent to the server. If you use a technique like this then you should base your update rate on the rate in which players move in the game. By doing this you can ensure that players don't slip through walls or run past a trigger too quickly.

Your second question I would use boost::asio to set up a service that your clients can 'ping' by sending a simple packet, then the service would send a message back to the client and you could determine the time it took to get the packet returned.

Comment: the suggestion makes a lot of sense .. however in my scenario this wont really work .. In my game, the client sends the position of its player, the server, also does some calculations based on this position and the position of other players, and other objects in the scene. If the client sends only some of the position upadtes, then the server doesnt always know accurate positions of clients and hence may perform incorect calculations

Comment: @AnkurVj:  Why does the client send the position of the player?  Is there some unusual requirement here?  Typically, the client sends player commands, and the server determines things like positions.  Otherwise, people are going to hack the client or connection to allow themselves to be wherever they like whenever they like.

Comment: @David Thornley: You are exactly right, the players can easily hack their clients or do things like speed hacks with the greatest of ease. @AnkurVj: you might rethink your design, the server really does need to be the ultimate authority on player position.

Comment: @Kyle, David, absolutely valid point,  please see the comments to my question

Comment: btw the asio thing would help me a lot with its "timer" feature , nice

Comment: For movement, it's common to have a client send its claimed position and for the server to verify it. Sending 'commands' doesn't work well for fine-grained movement activities. This is doubly important when using UDP because you don't want to have to retransmit such data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to end up doing raw-packet stuff, you might as well roll your own ICMP packet; the structure is trivial (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping).

Answer (score 0):

The [enet](http://enet.bespin.org/) library does a lot of the networking for you. It calculates latency as well.